# Cloning a project from bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I tried to clone a project from bitbucket but the following error occured (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP2X8.png).
I searched for this error but couldn't find anything. The error message says:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2014-09-21 11:04:26.496
!MESSAGE https://<myusername>@bitbucket.org/<myusername>/<project name>.git: authentication not supported
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://<myusername>@bitbucket.org/<myusername>/<project name>.git: authentication not supported
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://<myusername>@bitbucket.org/<myusername>/<project name>.git: authentication not supported
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:175)
    ... 3 more
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try without the first username? `https://@bitbucket.org/<myusername>/<project name>.git`. Also double-check the url for typos.

Comment: Is it a public or private repo?

Comment: @VonC private repo but I can't clone public repos too. GitHub repos work well.

Comment: can you clone any bitbucket repo form command line?

Comment: @VonC yes, I can clone both private and public bitbucket repos.

Comment: But not through Eclipse and its EGit plugin, right? Is Eclipse configured with any kind of proxy in its setting?

Comment: Yes, using git for windows. No, I just downloaded Eclipse and didn't change anything. @VonC

Comment: Have you found any workaround for this problem?

Comment: @fcs unfortunately, no

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has come across this problem, it is most probably related with JVM locale used to run Eclipse. Adding -Duser.language=en at the end of eclipse.ini file solved our problems.